# Display content off screen when running game (MacBook retina)

Tags: windows, graphics-card, macbook, boot-camp

When running *The Evil Within* on my MacBook Pro with the GT750M, the content is offset when the game is in fullscreen mode like this:

[image: Game screenshot]

I've installed the latest NVidia-Drivers and it's all working well when on the Windows UI, but in-game there is this offset. What could I try to fix this?

Comment: There should be an `Auto adjustment` button **on the monitor**. Press it.

Comment: This is a laptop and there is **no monitor** attached, it's the internal display that causes this issue.

Comment: I'd post up on the game's site. Never seen that happen before on Mac [& no, there is no auto adjust on a Mac screen, it should never need it]